# How it is out of rangeIndex was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: i

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4Mo.png)When i run this code and all responses are ok but if on more response added in my class it shows an error and i am stuck in it. please help me out. I will be thankful to you.

```
else if(auths.Count != payable.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < payable.Length; i++)

            {

                var item = new PayableTransfers
                {
                    URN = payable[i].uniqueReferenceNumber,
                    OperationDate = payable[i].operationDate,
                    TransactionCode = payable[i].transactionCode,
                    IsBlocked = payable[i].isBlocked,
                    PaymentMode = payable[i].paymentMode,
                    DestinationCode = payable[i].destinationCode,
                    DestinationAddress = payable[i].destinationAddress,
                    IsIncident = payable[i].isIncident,
                    IsRequestedForCancelation = payable[i].isRequestedForCancelation


                };
                var set = payable[i].uniqueReferenceNumber;
                var setss = sets[i];
                if (setss == set)
                {
                    repositorylist.Update(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    repositorylist.Add(item);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: in which line, probably your collection does not have the specified index?

Comment: var setss = sets[i];
9th number from bottom

Comment: yes it have 9 element fetching from database and set(response) have 13 elements

Comment: loop works properly but when index reach the value equals to sets it shows an error

Comment: just add a check before you assign the value

Comment: kindly explain your answer.

Comment: There is no way to explain, the error itself shows what is the reason, if you want give me team viewer, i can fix it

Comment: ok i will give you team viewer id and password after intallation

Comment: how i can give you id and password, you have have skype id or personal email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of sets you access does not hold any value, You need to check for value

```
var setss = sets[i];
if(i < payable.length -1 )
{
if (setss.contains(set[i])
{
   repositorylist.Update(item);
}
}
```